# RedirectURI does not redirect for Mobile using WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to use Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticator to Authenticate using Azure AD which in turn should call back to my mobile app with an WebAuthenticatorResult.  The process works up to the point where the Callback URI should callback into my app.

1. Command in Mobile App is fired calling the AuthenticateAsync method.
2. A new web browser opens on the mobile and I am prompted to enter my Microsoft Credentials
3. Sign in using my organisations user credentials.
4. Sign in successful.
5. Error message displays

[image: Undefined Sign-on URL for app "Mobile SSO" Error]

The callback URI is never fired and the only option I have is to close the browser which then throws an exception in my app, this is expected when the process fails or the user closes the browser.  The authentication result is never returned in my app.

What I expect to happen is once the authentication was successful the browser would redirect the browser to the RedirectURI and my mobile app would handle it.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work or have I misconfigured something?

WebAuthenticator called from my ViewModel

```
async Task<bool> SSOLogin()
        {
            ErrorMessage = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var authRequestUrl = new Uri("https://myapps.microsoft.com/signin/2borno2-1234-abcd-baba-42aaa70ab1da?tenantId=ab12ac17-4321-acbd-1234-72aae60ed1ca6");
                
                var callbackUrl = new Uri("mobile://myapp");

                var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions
                {
                    Url = authRequestUrl,
                    CallbackUrl = callbackUrl,
                    PrefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
                });

                var accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                var msg = e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Activity to handle callback URI (mobile://myapp)

```
    [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "mobile")]
    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {

    }
```

Azure AD Application Setup
[image: Azure Application set up]

[image: Azure application set up with the redirectURI]

N.B. the tenant Id and client ids are not the actual ones I'm using.  I'm confident these are working as the browser in the mobile app takes me to the correct log in page and the error message displays the application name I've set up in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

The sign-on URL error in your screenshot ("Undefined sign-on url for app") typically indicates that you need to set the Home Page URL under the app registration's branding tab.

[image]

From your other screenshot I am unable to tell whether you have selected the checkbox next to the mobile://myapp URL to make it the default. If you haven't done that and  have multiple Redirect URIs added, the first one will get selected by default.

Comment: Thanks, I initially did add the Home Page URL.  After sign in (via the browser that opens in the mobile app), it then redirects to the home page instead of the displaying the "undefined sign on" error.  What should happen is the browser redirects to the RedirectURI/callbackURL specified in the request, which it's not doing.

Also there is no check box next the "mobile://myapp" URI and Azure AD.  Which appears to be expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the **Microsoft.Identity.Client** nuget package instead and configured the Mobile app platforms in Azure AD.

```
public class AzureADTokenService
{
    // Replace these with your details
    readonly string AndroidAppId = "YOUR.APP.NAME";
    readonly string GeneratedAndroidAppSignature = "1234567890asdfghjkl";
    readonly string iOSAppId = "YOUR.PACKAGE.BUNDLENAME";
    readonly string AzureADClientID = "aaaaaaaa-1111-2222-3333-444444444444";
    readonly string AzureADTenantID = "aaaaaaaa-1111-2222-3333-444444444444";

    private IParentWindowLocatorService _parentWindowLocatorService;
    readonly List<string> Scopes = new List<string> { "user.read" };

    private IPublicClientApplication _pca;

    string RedirectUri
    {
        get
        {
            if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
                return $"msauth://{AndroidAppId}/{GeneratedAndroidAppSignature}";
            else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
                return $"msauth.{iOSAppId}://auth";

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public AzureADTokenService(IParentWindowLocatorService parentWindowLocatorService)
    {
        _parentWindowLocatorService = parentWindowLocatorService;

        // Create tha application
        _pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AzureADClientID)
            .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
            .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, AzureADTenantID)
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task<string> SignInAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            // Attempt to sign in silently using existing cached tokens
            if (firstAccount != null)
                result = await _pca.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
            else
            {
                var builder = _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                                        .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true);

                if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
                {
                    var windowLocatorService = _parentWindowLocatorService.GetCurrentParentWindow();
                    builder = builder.WithParentActivityOrWindow(windowLocatorService);
                }

                result = await builder.ExecuteAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            var builder = _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                                        .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true);

            if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
            {
                 var windowLocatorService = _parentWindowLocatorService.GetCurrentParentWindow();
                 builder = builder.WithParentActivityOrWindow(windowLocatorService);
            }

            result = await builder.ExecuteAsync();
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SignOutAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();

            // Go through all accounts and remove them.
            while (accounts.Any())
            {
                await _pca.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
                accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```